# Indefinite Integral involving infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

[image]

So in this problem, I think the only way to go is to involve the maclaurin series of exp(x) function in some way so that factors cancel out but i cant figure out how to do so. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Start with $f_n(x)^2 + \exp(2x) = (f_n(x) + i \exp(x))(f_n(x) - i \exp(x))$ and use partial fractions.  Then use the fact that $x^n/n! = f_n(x) + i \exp(x) - (f_n(x) + i \exp(x))'$.

Comment: By using this method, the answer that I got is \frac{-n!i}{2}\ln(\frac{fn(x)+ie^{x}}{fn(x)-ie^{x}}) but the answer given in the answer key is (-n!)tan^-1[fn(x)/exp(x)]

Comment: Basically Sir I am not able to convert the final answer I obtained in the complex form, to the real form. There is term of log{fn(x) +iexp(x)}-log{fn(x)-iexp(x)} and i cant convert it to real. Also , the answer given in the sheet is in term of tan^-1 (tan inverse).

Comment: Is it because of different ways of approaching the problem which gives 2 forms of answer because both answers on differentiating give the original integrand so both answers are correct @Robert Israel